# Recent upgrade to 20.04 - Slow KDE Window Rendering

Tags: nvidia, kde, 20.04

Recently upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 (In place). PC Specs at bottom. Running KDE Plasma, with minimal else (widgets / non standard decorations etc) installed. Seeing very slow open times of some basic apps (KDE Settings, Discover) with just the bouncing cursor, and simple things like confirmation windows (Save yes / no / cancel) remaining blank for a good 3 seconds or so before being populated.

Looking at top when these slow loads are happening, I see XOrg shooting to the top of the list with 45-50% CPU (Not sure if this is of the current clock or total clock?)

Running a Ryzen 9 3900x with 32gb Ram and an NVidia 1070 on the NVidia-driver-440, driving 3 monitors (2560x1440 x2, 3440x1440x1)

EDIT: Image to show example of unpopulated save box. This gave me long enough to deal with spectacle to grab the image. 
[Screengrab save dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1LyN.png)

EDITEDIT: `lshw -c video` output:

```
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:135 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

EDITEDITEDIT: `glxinfo -B` output

```
 name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 8192 MB
    Total available memory: 8192 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 7271 MB
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.64
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.64
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 440.64
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Comment: Are proprietary drivers in use?

Comment: Yes - using nvidia-driver-440 proprietary

Answer (score 0):

and everything was fine under 19.10 ? I doubt it a specific problem with 20.04 but some settings got replaced or something. I would recommend first looking at `lshw -c video` you can post the output editing your question. and also look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file for warning and errors.

I don't have an nvidia anymore, but I remember there is a tool as well to introspec its performance.

you can also try to disable compositor temporarily for the sake of comparison. and also verify the rendering backend.

[image: compositor config dialog]

Update:

about the error you found in your Xorg.log, I found these very recent post about similar problem. I could not find if the solution was known yet. I hope it will help you.

- https://www.gamingonlinux.com/forum/topic/4304/page=2
- https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1730634.html
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254942

your video card might be too new?

what is the output of `glxinfo -B` ?

Comment: Same settings as you except OpenGL 3.1 here. Will post output!

Comment: Interestingly, from the output I see a fair (not a *huge*) amount of client bug: timer event2 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-1ms), your system is too slow
. The system isn't amazingly taxed (has a 12c Ryzen 9 and 32GB of RAM, currently only 12-16GB used, no VirtualBox etc running at the moment).

Comment: Added output from glxinfo - its an old 10 series card so hopefully not, in the supported list from the latest 440 NV Driver (also tried the older 435 with no help).

Answer (score 0):

Try switching back to the 435 driver and then restart.  That fixed the issue for me.